# Passing prop down to the child is causing Re-rendering of all the owners

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component `PP`, which has a decorator, that causes it to receive a props `patternStreams` every few seconds.
`PP` owns a component called `PPView` and passes it `patternStreams`, consecutively, `PPView` owns a `RP` component and passes it `patternStreams`.
By placing `console.log` within `render()` method of each component, I have noticed that it all 3 components are being redrawn every few seconds, when prop is being passed to `PP` component.
The only component that needs to be redrawn is `RP`, so how do I prevent rest of components from being redrawn ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lifecycle method called `shouldComponentUpdate` that does exactly what you need - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate

> Invoked before rendering when new props or state are being received.
>   This method is not called for the initial render or when forceUpdate
>   is used.
>
> Use this as an opportunity to return false when you're certain that
>   the transition to the new props and state will not require a component
>   update.